# What happens to Azure AD joined devices if you turn off user registration after they are joined?

Tags: entra-id

We discovered that the 'Users may join devices to Azure AD' setting in our Azure AD was set to 'All' by default. At this point we have a number of users personal devices joined. Before switching it to 'None' I'm trying to get a feel for what, if any, impact changing it will have on the already enrolled devices.

Answer (score 0):

This will not impact already registered devices. It will simply prevent new, unauthorized devices from being registered by users. You can safely turn it off.